# how to implement multi-level constraints using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Let's say I have a Warehouse -> Bin -> Part (Shape, Size, Color) relationship. We can easily have a unique index constraint on a Part which would allow me to flag a violation error for more than one same color part (e.g. only one "Red") per Bin.  However, what if I wanted to have a constraint that allowed me to only have one such part per Warehouse? How can I do this in EF?

Answer (score 0):

So, your domain entity classes would look something like this:

```
public enum ColorEnum : byte
{
    Red = 1,
    Blue = 2
}

public class Part
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }

    public ColorEnum Color { get; private set; }

    public Bin Bin { get; private set; }
    public int BinId { get; private set; }
}

public class Bin
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public Warehouse Warehouse { get; private set; }
    public short WarehouseId { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Part> Parts { get; private set; }
}

public class Warehouse
{
    public short Id { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Bin> Bins { get; private set; }
}
```

Since you want your Parts to now be of a unique color per Warehouse, it's now required for them to know about their Warehose. So add the reference to the Warehouse inside the Part class:

```
public class Part
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }

    public ColorEnum Color { get; private set; }

    public Bin Bin { get; private set; }
    public int BinId { get; private set; }

    public Warehouse Warehouse { get; private set; }
    public short WarehouseId { get; private set; }
}
```

Now we want to create a unique index on Part class for: (WarehouseId, Color).

We can achieve that in two ways:

1) By adding annotations to your Entity's properties (from the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`):

```
public class Part
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }

    [Index("UX_Warehouse_Color", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public ColorEnum Color { get; private set; }

    public Bin Bin { get; private set; }
    public int BinId { get; private set; }

    public Warehouse Warehouse { get; private set; }
    [Index("UX_Warehouse_Color", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public short WarehouseId { get; private set; }
}
```

2) By using the EntityFramework fluent API inside our `DbContext` class implementation, in the override for the `protected virtual void DbContext.OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder);` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Part>()
    .HasIndex(part => new { part.WarehouseId, part.Color })
    .IsUnique();
```